# Is there a way to conditionally not deserialize XML element using XmlSerializer in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, xmlserializer, xml-deserialization

I want not to deserialize some elements of an `XML` file, if some condition is met, for example, take a look a this code sample:

```
namespace Test
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static string _xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-16""?>
<ArrayOfPerson xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Kate</FirstName>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Johh</FirstName>
    <Age>THIS IS NOT NUMBER DO NOT SERIALIZE AGE FOR Johh</Age>
  </Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>";

        public static void Main()
        {
            var sr = new StringReader(_xml);
            var xmlDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
            var persons = xmlDeserializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I want to achieve here is not to deserialize Person's Age element and leave it default if their `FirstName = "John"`. I know there is [ShouldSerialize*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods) approach to conditionally serialize properties. Is there something similar for deserialization, or perhaps any other approach I can take to achieve conditional deserialization using `XmlSerializer` without implementing custom deserializer?

Comment: i think not but you could use OnDeserializingAttribute to save the default value somewhere and OnDeserializedAttribute to overwrite it after deserialization is finished

Comment: @MongZhu, the thing is that the structure of XML file is when `FirstName=John` his age will not be a number but some random gibberish (like the one I put in my example) that cannot be converted to a number, so I want to ignore deserialization altogether in this case. And I also don't want to make this field string because this it is number for all Persons who are not Johns.
So to answer your question - I cannot set a break point on a setter because at the point when setter is hit this field should be already converted to a number which will happen in my case.

Comment: You are right, it throws an exception at conversion point, irrespective of the setter logic.